# Which 'li' was clicked using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have some li elements:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>    
</ul>
```

I need to know the number of the element that was clicked. For example, if an user clicks on

```
<li>Three</li>
```

my output will be "3".

How can I get this result using vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script>
        let countOne = 0,
          countTwo = 0,
          countThree = 0;
      </script>

  </head>

  <body>



    <ul>
      <li onclick='countOne++'>One</li>
      <li onclick='countTwo++'>Two</li>
      <li onclick='countThree++'>Three</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="View Results" onclick="console.log(countOne, countTwo, countThree)"/>

  </body>

  </html>
```

It will return in the console the values.

Comment: Check your own result, OP wants something else, read the question properly.

Comment: @Durga, yes, you are right...